# Divide by zero, can't find the problem in this program which runs Euclid's algorithm to find the greatest common divisor

Tags: java, long-integer, division, divide-by-zero, euclidean-algorithm

```
public static long[] simp (long [] a) {
    long c = a[0];
    long d = a[1];
    if ( a[0]<0 ) {
        a[0] = -1*a[0];
    }
    if (a[1]>a[0]) {
        long v = a[0];
        a[0]=a[1];
        a[1]=v;
    }
    while (a[1] > 0) {
        long t = a[0];
        a[0] = a[1];
        a[1] = t%a[1];
        System.out.println(a[0]+"/"+a[1]);
    }
    a[0] = c/a[0];
    a[1] = d/a[0];
    System.out.println(a[0]+"/"+a[1]);
    return a;
}
```

I followed the steps of Euclid's algorithm but I was stunned when a divide by zero problem appeared. I don't know how it can happen.

Comment: Your question is incomplete: Which inputs are you provided that causes divide-by-zero, and on which line does the divide-by-zero occur?

Comment: note also that almost all your lines don't do anything (from `if (a[0] < 0` all the way to `a[0] = c/a[0]` - you set `c` __first__, then do a lot of work on `a[0]` and `a[1]`, then toss all that out and use `c`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce by passing positive values to your method. When I pass an array containing a 0 and a non-negative value, I do get the division by 0 error. Easy solution: document in your JavaDoc comment that your method will throw an `ArithmeticException` in this case: Finer solution: Validate your argument. If it is anything other than an array of length 2 containing two strictly positive numbers, throw an `IllegalArgumenttException` with an error message that is clear to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the below two lines.

```
a[0] = c/a[0];
a[1] = d/a[0];
```

First statement will make a[0] as 0 since c is 0.
Next statement will be 1/0.

Comment: I missed it. Perfect, thanks a lot

Comment: It’s not precisely what happens. If `a[0]` was already 0 from the outset, the first statement will be 0 / 0, which will throw the exception. If `a[0]` was not 0, then `c`will not be either, and none of the statements needs to give any problems.